# Simply Image in Django doesnot work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a field image in the class of my model using the next code

setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'photo_movies/'
```

model.py

```
class Movie(models.Model) :
    code = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    movie_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Using that, it is posible to see the upload button

[image]

The problem is when I want to access to the upload picture I get the next error

```
Request URL:         http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/films/movie/Pantaleon%20y%20las%20Visitadoras/photos/pantaleon.jpg/
movie object with primary key u'Pantaleon y las Visitadoras/photos/pantaleon.jpg' does not exist.
```

Could you help me please to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define MEDIA_URL to handle it.
docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-url
also, check TryDjango Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-4xmVk6xrg
it provides good explanations about both MEDIA and STATIC files